# Symfony Role Hierarchy

Tags: security, symfony

currently I'm building an application based on a legacy database.
Within this Database there are UserClasses e.g.:

UserclassEntity:

- id
- classname
- parent

  - UserclassEntity

so I have rewritten the core service and added my custom voter to security.voter:

```
security.role_hierarchy:
  class: AppBundle\Security\Role\RoleHierarchy
  arguments:
    - '%security.role_hierarchy.roles%'
    - '@app.user_class_repository'

security.access.admin_voter:
  class: AppBundle\Security\Voter\AdminVoter
  arguments: ['@security.role_hierarchy']
  tags:
    - { name: security.voter, priority: 400 }
  public: false
```

So I implemented all needed MEthods based on Original RoleHierarchy Class:

```
class RoleHierarchy extends orig_RoleHierarchy
{
  /**
   * @var array
   */
  private $hierarchy;
  /**
   * @var UserclassRepository
   */
  private $userClassRepository;
  /**
   * @var RoleManager
   */
  private $manager;
  /**
   * @var UserclassRepository
   */
  private $userclassRepository;

  /**
   * @param UserclassRepository $userclassRepository
   * @param array               $hierarchy
   */
  public function __construct(UserclassRepository $userclassRepository, array $hierarchy)
  {
      $this->hierarchy = $hierarchy;
      $this->userclassRepository = $userclassRepository;
      $map = $this->buildRolesTree($this->hierarchy);
      parent::__construct($map);
  }

  /**
   * Here we build an array with roles. It looks like a two-levelled tree -   just
   * like original Symfony roles are stored in security.yml
   *
   * @param array $hierarchy
   *
   * @return array
   */
  private function buildRolesTree(array $hierarchy = [])
  {
      $userclasses = $this->userclassRepository->findAll();
      foreach ($userclasses as $userclass) {
          /** @var $userclass Userclass */
          if ($userclass->getParent()) {
              if (!isset($hierarchy['ROLE_' . $userclass->getName()])) {
                  $hierarchy['ROLE_' . $userclass->getName()] = array();
              }
              $hierarchy['ROLE_' . $userclass->getName()][] = 'ROLE_' .   $userclass->getParent()->getName();
          } else {
              if (!isset($hierarchy['ROLE_' . $userclass->getName()])) {
                  $hierarchy['ROLE_' . $userclass->getName()] = array();
              }
          }
      }
      return $hierarchy;
  }
}
```

But when i clear the cache for prod environment i get an error:

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
Compile Error: require(): Failed opening required   'E:\projects\sf2\app\var\cache\pro_/doctrine/orm/Proxies\__CG__AppBundleEntityUserclass.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear')
```

This Exception throws because of missing Proxy Class, but I really don't know how to do this in another way. I need this Entity and I need the Role_Hierarchy based on this Entity.

Any Suggestions in how to fix this?

As suggested some more files:
doctrine's part of config.yml

```
doctrine:
dbal:
    driver:   pdo_mysql
    host:     "%database_host%"
    port:     "%database_port%"
    dbname:   "%database_name%"
    user:     "%database_user%"
    password: "%database_password%"
    charset:  LATIN1
    mapping_types:
      enum: string
orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
    entity_managers:
      default:
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true
        dql:
          string_functions:
            COLLATE: AppBundle\DQL\CollateFunction
```

Doctrine ORM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd">
  <entity name="AppBundle\Entity\Userclass" table="userclass" repository-class="AppBundle\Repository\UserclassRepository">
    <indexes>
      <index name="name" columns="name,classname,class,color"/>
    </indexes>
    <id name="id" type="integer" column="id">
      <generator strategy="AUTO"/>
    </id>
    <field name="name" type="string" column="name" length="50" nullable="false">
      <options>
        <option name="fixed"/>
      </options>
    </field>
    <field name="classname" type="string" column="classname" length="50" nullable="false">
      <options>
        <option name="fixed"/>
      </options>
    </field>
    <field name="class" type="integer" column="class" nullable="false">
      <options>
        <option name="unsigned"/>
      </options>
    </field>
    <field name="color" type="string" column="color" length="10" nullable="false">
      <options>
        <option name="fixed"/>
      </options>
    </field>
    <many-to-one field="parent" target-entity="AppBundle\Entity\Userclass">
        <join-column name="parent_id" referenced-column-name="id" />
    </many-to-one>
  </entity>
</doctrine-mapping>
```

Comment: Try to clear the cache manually (by removing all the folders in the `cache` dir) and execute `cache:clear` after, I used to have this kind of error on my windows dev machine. Also check `Userclass` entity name and file name, they must be the same.

Comment: I already tried this, also tried to run cache:clear with --no-warmup option. This ends up in the same error when trying to access the app on frontend.

Comment: Can you post your Userclass' ORM configuration as well as your doctrine section from config.yml? Also, unrelated to this issue I suppose, your security.role_hierarchy argument configuration is the wrong way around (should be repository service first, then roles parameter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried a lot of things but nothing really worked. As I found out, the proxy generate Task from doctrine:orm was removed in latest VErsion compatible with Symfony 3.1.x.

If someone struggle into this, the best way (I could find) was to set the 
auto_generate_proxy_classes from "%kernel.debug%" to true

```
orm:
   auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
```

As simple as hell, only in dev environment this parameter is true. Running the application in productive mode, turns this obviosly to false, so Proxyclasses are not generated as they are needed. The Role Hierarchy is somehow triggered before doctrine got a chance to generate those needed proxies.

By enabling this auto_generate-option those proxies are generated as they were needed, and also cached. So any minimal performance break will only happen once. After generation these classes als also cached.

On my application I was not able to find any relevant or even little performance issues.